# How to get the unique items based on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter, unique-constraint

I am having a Javascript snippet to store only unique items in a array of objects like this:-

```
const array = [
    {id: 3, name: 'Central Microscopy', fiscalYear: 2018},
    {id: 5, name: 'Crystallography Facility', fiscalYear: 2018},
    {id: 3, name: 'Central Microscopy', fiscalYear: 2017},
    {id: 5, name: 'Crystallography Facility', fiscalYear: 2017},
    {id: 3, name: 'Central Microscopy', fiscalYear: 2019},
  ];
  const result = [];
  const map = new Map();
  for (const item of array) {
    if (!map.has(item.id) ) {
      map.set(item.id, true); // set any value to Map
      result.push({
        id: item.id,
        name: item.name,
        fiscalYear: item.fiscalYear
      });
    }
  }
  console.log(result);
```

for this result is

```
[
  { id: 3, name: 'Central Microscopy', fiscalYear: 2018 },
  { id: 5, name: 'Crystallography Facility', fiscalYear: 2018 }
]
```

Now I want to have unique items and have those items whose fiscal years are greater than existing items.
For example:-
For the same input, the output should be as:- i need the code in javascript or typescript(Language constraint)

```
[
  { id: 3, name: 'Central Microscopy', fiscalYear: 2019},
  { id: 5, name: 'Crystallography Facility', fiscalYear: 2018 }
]
```

Need an optimal solution even if the data is large

Comment: You've worded your question like you're assigning us a task. What have you done? This isn't a McDonald's drive-thru.

Comment: I feel that ive asked some improvement.If possible plese try to help me

Comment: You've given us a list of requirements that the code should be in a certain language, and should be optimal. You haven't shown what you've tried, and what isn't working with your attempted solution.

Comment: Ive already given that my solution output is 
`
[
  { id: 3, name: 'Central Microscopy', fiscalYear: 2018 },
  { id: 5, name: 'Crystallography Facility', fiscalYear: 2018 }
]
` 
and now I need the output as 
```
[
  { id: 3, name: 'Central Microscopy', fiscalYear: 2019},
  { id: 5, name: 'Crystallography Facility', fiscalYear: 2018 }
]
```
where I am invovling a condition for fiscalYear greater that should be accepted

Comment: And either javascript or typescript both are accepted(any of them)

Comment: So try to write the code to get that result, and if you get stuck on something specific, ask about it. This is a pretty simple programming problem. I see no evidence that you've tried to solve it for yourself before asking someone else to do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let array = [
    {id: 3, name: 'Central Microscopy', fiscalYear: 2018},
    {id: 5, name: 'Crystallography Facility', fiscalYear: 2018},
    {id: 3, name: 'Central Microscopy', fiscalYear: 2027},
    {id: 3, name: 'Central Microscopy', fiscalYear: 2017},
    {id: 5, name: 'Crystallography Facility', fiscalYear: 2017},
    {id: 3, name: 'Central Microscopy', fiscalYear: 2019},
    {id: 3, name: 'Central Microscopy', fiscalYear: 2021},
  ];
  
  let temp = array.filter((elem) => elem.fiscalYear >= 2018)
  let cache = {}

  temp.forEach((elem) => {
      if(cache[elem.name]){
          if(cache[elem.name].fiscalYear < elem.fiscalYear){
              cache[elem.name] = elem;
          }
      }
      else{
           cache[elem.name] = elem;
      }
  })

  let result = Object.values(cache);
  console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think you missed the point of the year requirements, but can't blame you. With a marginal description and no attempt to solve it, it can be easy to miss.

Comment: I assume, I have covered the case you are trying to point here.Still, if I have missed, please point it out.

Comment: Well, they accepted your answer, but I don't think they understand it. There's no indication that they want an arbitrary year as a filter. This is the problem when people ask for code without showing any attempt to solve it themselves.

Comment: I think you are the one having trouble understanding the solution.It is clear and covers all the cases.Try running code snippet and tell me a case where you think it might fail.I'll be happy to know.

Comment: And so if all objects with a particular ID all have a year that's less than 2018?

Comment: Also, you're not making copies of the object, like the OP is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add one more filter in loop,

```
  let bigYear = item.fiscalYear

  let filteredItem = array.filter((e=>e.id===item.id && e.fiscalYear > bigYear))[0]

  result.push(filteredItem ? {...filteredItem} : item);
```

****Final** Snippet will look alike,**

```js
const array = [
    {id: 3, name: 'Central Microscopy', fiscalYear: 2018},
    {id: 3, name: 'Central Microscopy', fiscalYear: 2029},
    {id: 3, name: 'Central Microscopy', fiscalYear: 2017},
    {id: 5, name: 'Crystallography Facility', fiscalYear: 2017},
    {id: 5, name: 'Crystallography Facility', fiscalYear: 2018},
  ];
  const result = [];
  const map = new Map();
  for (const item of array) {
    if (!map.has(item.id) ) {
      map.set(item.id, true); // set any value to Map
      let bigYear = item.fiscalYear
      let filteredItem = array.filter((e=>e.id===item.id && e.fiscalYear > bigYear))[0]
      result.push(filteredItem ? {...filteredItem} : item);
    }
  }
  console.log(result);
```

Comment: You're already using a `Map`, so why bother with the filter? You can just check if the current `item` is greater than the one in the map (if any).

Comment: here we are not adding every item into the `Map`, we use `Map` just as a mediator to validate item with a unique id. for the latest year we need iterate over the original array to get a unique item with the latest year.

Comment: Oh right, you're still setting `true`. I mean since you're using a map, then set the object as the value, and you can then do a direct comparison. No need to filter every time.